# Python Variable Scope and Classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, if I define a variable:

```
my_var = (1,2,3)
```

and try to access it in `__init__` function of a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print my_var
```

I can access it and print `my_var` without stating (global my_var).

If I put `my_var` right after `class MyClass` however, I get scope error `(no global variable found)`.

What is the reason for this? How should I do this? Where can I read about this to learn? I did read Python Class page but I did not encounter its explanation.

Thank you

Comment: it's not a global variable anymore when you put it inside class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you put it right after `class MyClass`, it becomes a class attribute and you can get access to it via `MyClass.my_var` or as `self.my_var` from within the class (provided you don't create an *instance* variable with the same name).

Here's a little demo:

```
my_var = 'global'
class MyClass(object):
   my_var = 'class' 
   def __init__(self):
      print my_var #global
      print MyClass.my_var #class
      print self.my_var #class -- Only since we haven't set this attribute on the instance
      self.my_var = 'instance' #set instance attribute.
      print self.my_var #instance
      print MyClass.my_var #class
```

Comment: if you put it in `__init__`, this means that this is only initialized when an object is created.

Comment: @ronak -- I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @mgilson: beware: in this case the first `print self.my_var" will print the class variable (containing (4,5,6), not (1,2,3).

Comment: While an instance attribute with the name `my_var` is not created, tries to access it will yield the class attribute instead - not the global variable.

Comment: @jsbueno -- I did run it beforehand -- the class variable is `(1,2,3)`, the global is `(4,5,6)`, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying ...

Comment: Changed to use more meaningful data for the variables (to make it easier to track what is what)

Comment: @mgilson I meant to say that if you use `my_var` in the class definition (right after `class MyClass`) then it is a class variable and if you include it in the `__init__` function, you will have to create an object to access that variable.  You answer is correct and I gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 12):

Complementing @mgilson's answer:
Note that Python Class variables are shared among the class instances. And the behaviour might be VERY unexpected and seem weird. In practice it works like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_var = 10

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.my_var)


m1 = MyClass()
print(m1.my_var)
>>> 10          # this is fine

MyClass.my_var = 20
print(m1.my_var)
>>> 20          # WTF? :) --> shared value

m2 = MyClass()
print(m2.my_var)
>>> 20          # this is expected

m1.my_var = 30
print(MyClass.my_var)
>>> 20          # this is also expected

MyClass.my_var = 40 
print(m1.my_var)
>>> 30           # But WHY? Isn't it shared? --> 
                 # The value WAS shared until m1.my_var = 30 has happened.

print(m2.my_var)
>>> 40           # yep m2.my_var's value is still shared :)
```

Comment: BasicWolf, since @mgilson's answer was a bit more on the subject, I could not help but choose it as the correct answer. But I sincerely thank you so much for this excellent, truly great explanation. It made me understand a lot, on top of what mgilson clearified. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you write:

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_var = (1, 2, 3)
```

you are defining an attribute of `MyClass`, not a variable. In your `__init__` method, then, it is `MyClass.my_var`.

Answer (score 1):

Once it's inside the `class` definition, it's no longer global, it's now in the class object's namespace.  You can access it with `self.my_var` within `__init__` though...