# Python: variable scope and "instance has no attribute"

Tags: python, scope

I am confused about instance and class variables in python. I am confused about how this code:

```
class A:
    def _init__(self):
        print "initializer called"
        #l is an instance variable
        self.l = []
        print len(l)
    def printList(self):
        print len(self.l)

a = A()
print "here"
a.printList()
```

produces the following output:

```
here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\a.py", line 16, in <module>
    a.printList()
  File "C:\Python27\a.py", line 10, in printList
    print len(self.l)
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'l'
```

Is the initializer not being called? Why does "here" print, but the print statement in the initializer doesn't? Should 'l' be a class variable? I thought making it an instance variable using 'self' would be sufficient, is that not correct? Am I incorrect about the scope of these variables?

I have looked at these sources, but they didn't help:

[Python: instance has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938917/python-instance-has-no-attribute)

[Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

[Python - Access class variable from instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577578/python-access-class-variable-from-instance)

[Python Variable Scope and Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941748/python-variable-scope-and-classes)
[instance has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158202/instance-has-no-attribute)

Comment: `_init__` only has one underscore at the beginning.  It needs two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a method named `_init__`, not `__init__`. The number of underscores is important. Without the *exact* correct name, it's just a weirdly named method, not the instance initializer at all. You end up using the default initializer (which sets no attributes). You also have an error in your `_init__` (you refer to `l` unqualified). Fixing the two, your initializer would be:

```
def __init__(self):    # <-- Fix name
    print "initializer called"
    #l is an instance variable
    self.l = []
    print len(self.l)  # <-- Use self.l; no local attribute named l
```